# Как вынести Pattern за пределы цикла?

Tags: java

мой код:

```
for (String line : lines) {
     Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(line);
}
```

нужно вынести pattern за пределы цикла.
Подскажите, как это сделать, если в паттерне я использую 1 строку?

Comment: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как обычно - в переменную:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
for (String line : lines) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
}
```

Или я что то не понял?

Comment: спасибо большое;)